# return a filtered array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, duplicates

I'm struggling with removing dupes from an array of objects. I have an array, storedItems:

```
var storedItems = [
    {text: "1", checked: false },
    {text: "2", checked: false },
    {text: "3", checked: false },
    {text: "string", checked: false }
]
```

etc. the text values are either strings or numeric strings. I'm ok with identifying the unique text values, either in the hash or in uniqueVals ...

```
filterDupes(storedItems);

function filterDupes(input) {
    var hash = {};
    var uniqueVals = [];
    input.forEach(obj => {
        hash[obj.text] = true;
    })
    var uniqueVals = Object.keys(hash); // Array
    return input.filter(function(obj, ix, arr) {
        uniqueVals.indexOf(obj.text) !== -1; // NOPE
    }) // .filter
} // filterDupes
```

... it's how to compare either the hash keys or uniqueVals to the input array objects, i.e., what exactly I need (w/out a for loop or another forEach?) to return the filtered array, that's got me bashing my head against a wall, trying to find some version of return hash[obj.text] == obj.text; or return (hash.key === obj.text)

EDIT: fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/WTFoxtrot/by3nhy4n/2/

Comment: You probably want to use Set object https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set instead of running forEach loop  then Object.keys method.

Comment: What does the code you showed do now? Does it not work? If it does not work, in what way does it not work?

Comment: @Yanaro re: Set object, yes indeed, I've just learned of it, thank you.

Comment: @torazaburo The code I showed returns an empty array.

Comment: You have to return something from your filter function.

Comment: @torazaburo indeed, that was the question

Comment: Check my V2 to see if that answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a combination of [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
let items = [
    {text: "1", checked: false},
    {text: "2", checked: false},
    {text: "3", checked: false},
    {text: "string", checked: false},
    {text: "2", checked: false},
    {text: "string", checked: false},
    {text: "1", checked: false}
];
let values = items.map(it => it.text).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);

console.log(values); // ["1", "2", "3", "string"]
```

The filter closure `(v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i` filters out all values that are present at any position other than the first occurrence of that value.

Using the same principles, if you want to filter the array of objects itself instead of returning a list of unique values, you can use `Array.prototype.filter()` with [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
let items = [
    {text: "1", checked: false},
    {text: "2", checked: false},
    {text: "3", checked: false},
    {text: "string", checked: false},
    {text: "2", checked: false},
    {text: "string", checked: false},
    {text: "1", checked: false}
];
let filtered = items.filter((x, i, a) => a.find(y => x.text === y.text) === x);

console.log(filtered); // [{"text": "1", "checked": false}, {"text": "2", "checked": false}, {"text": "3", "checked": false}, {"text": "string", "checked": false}]
```

Comment: Thank you! Your v2 is what I needed: I wanted to return the filtered array of objects, not simply the uniqueVals, which I had, using the hash. I'm curious about a couple of things; thought I read elsewhere that using a hash or Set() is more efficient than indexof, though I can't imagine how since your v1 values statement is so pretty. Also, while I read up on .find(), I would greatly appreciate, if you have a minute, an explanation of the .find statement - that's a bit of a mind-bender. Cheers, W

Answer (score 2):

V2: Using Set object, you migh use array indexOf the same way:

```
function filterDupes(input) {
  var unique = new Set();

  return input.filter((obj, ix, arr) => {
    if(!unique.has(obj.text)) {
       unique.add(obj.text);
       return true;
    }
    return false;
  })
}
```

If you don't want to change your function too much:

```
...
return input.filter((obj, ix, arr) => {
    var index = uniqueVals.indexOf(obj.text);
    if(index !== -1) {
    // Remove the element from unique array
       uniqueVals.splice(index,1);
       return true;
    }
    return false;
})
```

V1: **Incorrect**.
Previously, your function is kinda incorrect. It actually does nothing. You only push the text to an array then check if the text exists in that array, again.

```
var storedItems = [
  {text: "1", checked: false },
  {text: "2", checked: false },
  {text: "3", checked: false },
  {text: "string", checked: false }
];

function filterDupes(input) {
  //Your previous code inside function
  ...
  return input.filter(function(obj, ix, arr) {
     return uniqueVals.indexOf(obj.text) !== -1;
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The semicolons in the object were typos, I've edited my post, removing them. I think my fiddle (url in my post) is what you're suggesting but still I have nothing returned (actually in jsfiddle I get nothing, and in a repl I return an empty object). What am I missing?

Comment: Many thanks for elaborating on this. In the interest of understanding I've tried both of these. I *greatly* appreciate your providing a solution that builds on what I had; personally I find this most helpful, perhaps due to stubbornness but nonetheless. That said, once I grokked your V1 I prefer it because it's clear and obviously more concise. I actually prefer it to the answer I accepted as it's more learner-friendly (but perhaps it's bad SO form to change the accepted answer?). I wish more answers on SO respected where the OP is coming from. Cheers!